# Spring boot REST service добавление нового item в БД

Tags: rest, spring-boot

Есть модель
Message

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message")
public class Message{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
    private String message;
    @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "CREATED")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date created;

    public Message() {}

    public Message(Long id, String message, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
        this.created = new Date();
    }
+ getters / setters
```

Контроллер MessageController

```
@RestController
//http://localhost:8080/api/messages
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/api/messages",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addMessage(@RequestBody Message newMessage) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(messageRepository.save(newMessage), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку

> 2016-11-06 10:52:53.857  WARN 1100 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP
>   message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of
>   com.sttech.springrest.model.Message out of START_ARRAY token  at
>   [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ccdce8a; line: 1, column: 1];
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of com.sttech.springrest.model.Message out of
>   START_ARRAY token  at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ccdce8a;
>   line: 1, column: 1]

Ответ от Postman

> "exception":
>   "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException", 
>   "message": "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of
>   com.sttech.springrest.model.Message out of START_ARRAY token\n at
>   [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ccdce8a; line: 1, column: 1];
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of com.sttech.springrest.model.Message out of
>   START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ccdce8a;
>   line: 1, column: 1]"

Ну я так понял я получаю массив и его надо перевести в объект?
Объясните на пальцах как.

Comment: что вы передаете в postman?

Comment: Я передавал неправильный формат json [{*}] вместо {*}

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в неправильной передачи Json данных.
Я отсылал массив

```
[
  {
    "message": "Hello World 11",
    "author": "ABC",
    "created": ""
  }
]
```

а не одиночный элемент

```
{
   "message": "Hello World 11",
   "author": "ABC",
   "created": ""
}
```

Для массива используется конструкция

```
public ResponseEntity<?> addMessages(@RequestBody List<Message> newMessages) {

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(messageRepository.save(newMessages), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```